# How to install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on Windows 10 Home "S"

Tags: security, visual-studio, runtime-error, windows-10s

Windows 10 Home S only installs apps that are verified for the Microsoft Store.  For example, Arduino IDE installed just fine.  I'd expect all Microsoft products to be verified for sure.  However, I've discovered that Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition won't install.  And I actually found the app ON THE MICROSOFT STORE!  How can I install this program?  I'm unable to enable the option "install apps from anywhere" option on Windows 10 Home S since its intended purpose is to deny apps that are malicious.

This is the error I get.

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 S DO NOT ALLOW to install Win32 programs outside of Windows Store. Use Windows 10 Home or Pro.

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows 10 Iso? You could try using VirtualBox and install it a VM

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is not supported on Windows 10 S.  According to the [system requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs) page under the supported operating systems section for this version of Visual Studio, Windows 10 S is not supported:

> Windows 10 version 1507 or higher: Home, Professional, Education, and Enterprise (LTSC and S are not supported)

Unfortunately, you will have to use a supported version of Windows to install this application.  Also, what you appear to have found on the Microsoft Store for Visual Studio is really just an external link that takes you to the Microsoft website for Visual Studio.